# Is movndq works?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-architecture, measurement, cpu-cache

My task is to calculate RAM Read/Write speed. 
I using asm inserts to avoid compiler optimizations. To measure time I use TSC and CPU frequency. To move data I use asm instruction MOVNTDQ which doesn't use cache hierarchy.

Problem is in results. Data rate (by datasheet) is 800 Mbps, and I got by my test > 2000 Mbps write speed.

```
void memory_notCache_write_128(void* src, long blocks_amount) 
{
    _asm    
    {
        mov ecx, blocks_amount
        mov     esi, src
    a20:
        movntdq [esi], xmm0
        movntdq [esi + 16], xmm1
        movntdq [esi + 32], xmm2
        movntdq [esi + 48], xmm3
        movntdq [esi + 64], xmm4
        movntdq [esi + 80], xmm5
        movntdq [esi + 96], xmm6
        movntdq [esi + 112], xmm7
        add esi,  128
        loop    a20;
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    unsigned __int64 tick1, tick2;
    const long nBytes = 32*KByte;   

    char* source = (char*)_mm_malloc(nBytes*sizeof(char),16);

    tick1 =  getTicks();
    memory_notCache_write_128(source, current_times.t128);
    tick2 =  getTicks();

    double time = (double)(tick2-tick1)/(ProcSpeedCalc());
    cout << "Time WRITE_128[seconds]:" << time << endl;
    cout << (double) nBytes / time / MByte << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Datasheet of RAM, that I used - http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/308537/ELPIDA/EBE11UE6ACUA-8G-E.html

Source code (was written for Win patform): https://bitbucket.org/closed_eyes/ram_speed_for_win/downloads/memory_test.cpp

Comment: Please, post full source code. I would try to run it.

Comment: 800Mbps? Are you sure about that? RAM tends to be [way faster than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths#Random_access_memory) (I know those are theoretical, but still...)

Comment: Bytes, not bits.  The 64-bit data bus width helps, that's 8 bytes a whack.  5 gigabytes/second for DDR2 is pretty typical.

Comment: Ruben, I add source code. CAFxX, may be I was wrong but specification by datasheet said - 800 Mbps = 100 MBps. Ooh, my mistake, not 2000 Mbps but > 2000 MBps.

Comment: Hans Passant, can you tell some free utilites to get real RAM speed?

Comment: See this question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260602/how-to-increase-performance-of-memcpy

Comment: @YuryLapitsky by the way, if you're just trying to figure out the performance of your system, just use memtest86 or memtest86+.  The latter comes on Ubuntu install CDs and can just be run at boot.  You can also just download ISOs.  Either one will tell you memory and cache bandwidth.

Comment: @Nathan Binkert thank you, I'll try, but my interest not only attempting to get info about current system. It's also project that is interesting to create.

Comment: @CAFxX I was wrong, MemTest86+ display the same result 2235 MB/s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use non-temporal operations for this sort of code.  The real way to build a memory performance tester is to use the access pattern to make sure that you never hit in the cache.  Generally, this is done by looping over a very large chunk of memory that is bigger than the last level of cache in your system where your stride is the same as the cache line size.  If you do this, you'll ensure that every access will be a cache miss in all levels.  Don't forget though that when you read just one byte from memory, the processor will fetch a whole cache line, so if you do a 64-bit load, on a machine with a 64-byte cache line (very common), you should be counting 64-bytes as being read from memory.

Comment: Nathan Binkert, but how can I know the size of the cache line of current machine to be sure that I counting exactly? And is it legal to count 64 bytes, when I really read only 1/8. I look for the method of moving large chunks of memory but I didn't found more effective that "movdqa". Can you post some example, or help with instructions that can perform such work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate?  DRAM bandwidth?  If so, sure, count 64-bytes when you only read one.  Otherwise, you can just read the whole cache line and you'll get 1 cache miss and 7 hits.  You can find out the cache size in the manual for the chip, though there are ways to figure it out in software.  Finally, you're trying to do something that's not simple.  You have multiple levels of cache, tlbs, prefetcher, etc.  All affect performance.  Also, if you have an 4 or 8 core chip, you'll likely never saturate memory bandwidth without software prefetching or multithreaded code.

Answer (score 2):

Yury, your idea of using movntdq to measure 'physical' memory channel bandwidth is correct. I agree with Nathan Binkert on how to address 'system-wide' memory performance however I'd like to elaborate on your original questions on movntdq applicability in general and 800Mbps confusion.

Short version:

1. `movntdq` works fine and is ok to be used when you want to measure bandwidth of 'physical' memory channel.
2. 800Mbps is a 'bit-lane' specification. Each (of possibly two) memory controller channel is 64-bit wide. Two memory controller channels will deliver near to 1600MBytes/s raw write performance, however this still does not match with your actual measurements so please take a look on details below.
3. really stop using rdtsc. Use *only* `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter` for yor profiling and increase test buffer size if you face problems with measurement precision.
4. please specify details of your hardware platform (cpu, number of sodimms etc.) make sure you don't have any memory overclocking in bios setup.

Longer version.

1. As in short version: movntdq is okay. You must align series of movntdq writes to be a multiple of cpu cache line (64 bytes) and you must align beginning of `movntdq` write to a 64-byte boundary. Using non-aligned access will result in invalidation of non-temporal hint of the instruction so both `memory_notCache_write_32` and `memory_notCache_write_16` functions are not right choice of using `movndq` instruction.
2. As in short version: 800Mbps is a single bit-lane speed. `SODIMM` data path is 64 bits same as cpu/northbridge memory channel. When talking about `movntdq` instructions there are most probably two memory channels but they will operate in a 'dual-channel' mode only if there are two matching sodimms installed in a right memory slots on a mainboard. Two channels should effectively give you 1600 Mbytes/s while single-channel will give you 800Mbytes/s performance. Your actual figures became not so much different from 1600Mbytes/s estimation however they are still far from a close match. This might be from both incorrect measurement method (see point 3) and/or overclocked memory (not likely, but just in case see point 4).
3. "`QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter` should be enough for everyone" :) Seriously, just stop using `rdtsc` at all at this stage of your project. 3+ MHz timer precision (`QueryPerformanceFrequency`) will be okay when you measure memory write performance over 10Mbytes memory region. Consider theoretical memory bandwidth of 1600MBytes/s each tick of 3MHz timer will result in 533 bytes 'measurement error' which is nothing when writing 10Mbytes. rdtsc is very tricky stuff mainly because it's not stable over time on cpus with power management enabled (I am certain you are not on the 2nd/3rd generation of intel core cpus where `rdtsc` delivers stable counting). Please start with system-provided functions for timing measurements to have your measurements done right. It's also worth to check what value is given by `QueryPerformanceFrequency` on your platform.
4. Since you are measuring physical memory channel bandwidth it's worth to specify what hardware platform you are using for such measurements. Please make sure you don't have any manual memory timing settings in bios setup (having 533MHz memory bus will deliver 2+GBytes/s memory bandwidth given that memory controller is in dual-channel mode). Given that you are using an embedded system (`SODIMM`) there's a chance that memory controller settings are tweaked in bios. Just double-check there are no overclocking settings.

As a conclusion - don't use `rdtsc`, use only `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and `QueryPerformanceCounter`, keep using aligned versions memory writes with `movntdq` and check configuration of your embedded system. I would also strongly recommend complete avoidance of inline assembly usage and switch to using `_mm_stream_si128` instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba08y07y.aspx)